# Probability in cdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A random variable Y has cdf:

$$F(y) = \begin{cases}
  0       & y < 0 \\
  \ln(y)  & 1 \le y \le e \\
  1       & e < y \end{cases}$$

Find:

1. $P(Y < 2)$
2. $P(2 < Y < 2.5)$
3. $P(2 < Y \le 2.5)$
4. $f(y)$

For 4, I used differentiation to obtain $\dfrac{1}{y}$ for $1 \le y \le e$

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please show what you've tried for solving this question and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type math formulae :)

Comment: Use $P(Y\leq y)=F(y)$

Comment: Hint: continuity of cdf $F$ implies that $P(Y=y)=0$ for every $y$.

Comment: Thx @Alex, I've tried to use MathJax but I found it's hard for me in the first time to use it, it took so long time without success.
And of course I tried to solve it but couldn't
for example 
1- I tried : putting p(y<2) = ln(2) - ln(1) = ln(2) but I think it's wrong as there is no (=) in the p(y<2)
and stopped as the following to 1 has the same idea that stopped me in 1

Comment: 1) $P(Y<2)=P(Y\leq 2)-P(Y=2)=P(Y\leq 2)-0=P(Y\leq 2)=F(2)=\ln 2$ See my former comment telling you that $P(Y=2)=0$.

Comment: Oh, I got it now,

Answer (score 0):

1-

$P(Y<2) = P(Y<=2) - P(Y=2)$

$P(Y<2) = P(Y<=2) - 0$

$P(Y<2) = F(2) = ln(2)$

---

2-

$P(2<Y<2.5) = P(Y < 2.5) - P(Y<2)$

$P(2<Y<2.5) = ln(2.5) - ln(2)$

---

3-

$P(2<Y≤2.5) = P(Y < 2.5) - P(Y<2)$

$P(2<Y<2.5) = ln(2.5) - ln(2)$

4-

$\frac{1}{Y} , 1≤y≤e$